# SVM with rolling window

Tags: r, svm, sliding-window

I have a code which predict the change in the sign of future returns.

```
library(quantmod)
library(PerformanceAnalytics)
library(forecast)
library(e1071)
library(caret)
library(kernlab)
library(dplyr)
library(roll)
# get data yahoo finance
getSymbols("^GSPC", from = "1990-01-01", to = "2017-12-01") 
# take logreturns
rnull <- CalculateReturns(prices = GSPC$GSPC.Adjusted ,method ="log")
# lags 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 as features
feat <- merge(na.trim(lag(rnull,1)),na.trim(lag(rnull,2)),na.trim(lag(rnull,3)),na.trim(lag(rnull,4)),na.trim(lag(rnull,5)),all=FALSE)
# create dataset. 6th column is actural. Previous is lagged
dataset <- merge(feat,rnull,all=FALSE)
# set columns' names
colnames(dataset) = c("lag.1", "lag.2", "lag.3","lag.4","lag.5","TARGET")
# get signs and make a data.frame
x <- sign(dataset)%>%as.data.frame
# exclude 0 sign and assume that these values are positive
x[x==0] <- 1
# for svm purposes we need to set dependent variable as factor and make levels to interpretation
x$TARGET <- as.factor(as.character(x$TARGET))
levels(x$TARGET) <- list(positive = "1", negative = "-1")
# divide sample to training and test subsamples
trainindex <- x[1:5792,]
testindex <- x[5792:7030,]
# run svm
svmFit <- ksvm(TARGET~.,data=trainindex,type="C-svc",kernel= "rbfdot")
# prediction
predsvm <- predict(svmFit, newdata=testindex)
# results
confusionMatrix(predsvm, testindex$TARGET)
```

The next thing I am going to do is add a rolling window (1 step forecast) to my model.
However the basic methods as rollapply does not work with dataframe. Commom methods of one step forecast for time-series are also not valid for data.frame used in e1071 package.
I wrote the following function:

```
svm_next_day_prediction <- function(x){
      svmFit <- svm(TARGET~., data=x)
      prediction <- predict(object = svmFit, newdata = tail(x,1) )
      return(prediction) 
    }  


    apl = rollapplyr(data = x, width = 180, FUN = svm_next_day_prediction, by.column = TRUE)
```

but recieved a error because rollapply does not understand data.frames:

> Error in terms.formula(formula, data = data) :    '.' in formula and
>   no 'data' argument

Can you please explain how to apply rolling window for svm classification model with dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

A few points

- `rollapply` works with data frames that can be coerced to a matrix so be sure that your input is entirely numeric -- not a mix of numeric and factor.  For example, this works using the built-in data frame `BOD` which has two numeric columns.  Note that `x` passed to `pred` is a matrix here.

  ```
  pred <- function(x) predict(svm(demand ~ Time, x))
  rollapplyr(BOD, 3, FUN = pred, by.column = FALSE)
  ```

  giving

  ```
  ##              1        2        3
  ## [1,]  8.868888 10.86889 17.25474
  ## [2,] 11.661666 17.24870 16.00000
  ## [3,] 18.328435 16.18583 15.78583
  ## [4,] 16.230474 15.83247 19.56886
  ```
- I can't reproduce the error you get. I get a different error.
- the code in the question has `by.column = TRUE` (which is the default anyways)
  but that has the result of passing only a single vector to the function which 
  is not what you want.    You want `by.column = FALSE`.

Try this:

```
x0 <- data.matrix(x)
rollapplyr(data = x0, width = 180, FUN = svm_next_day_prediction, by.column = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks! The main problem is factor variables, required for classification problem.

Comment: A two level factor can be represented as a numeric column and, in general, a k level factor can be represented as k-1 columns.  `model.matrix(~ f)[, -1]`

Answer (score 0):

you can create a list with the individual data frames and then apply your function. I rename x to df to avoid confusion:

```
df=x
rowwindow=179
dfList=lapply(1:(nrow(df)-rowwindow),function(x) df[x:(rowwindow+x),])
result=sapply(dfList,svm_next_day_prediction)
```

Comment: It takes 8 hours and does not count some values due to multiple transformations. Anyway, Now it is clear and no errors appear.

Comment: if it takes so long you might want to try parallel programming https://www.r-bloggers.com/how-to-go-parallel-in-r-basics-tips/ and you also could consider PCA to reduce your variables. Also how about you reduce your lags and see if you do not get any worse results